# I find problem in importing django in vscode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, import

```
PS C:\Users\siruvani\projectsss\sshafeeq> workon try
PS C:\Users\siruvani\projectsss\sshafeeq> python manage.py startapp calxx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
      main()`enter code here`
    File "manage.py", line 17, in main
      ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django.
```

Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Comment: U use Vs Code or Visual Studio? Do u work from system `cmd` or from another one?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when using

```
python manage.py runserver #python version 3 was being used
```

Solved the problem by using:

```
python2 manage.py runserver #python version 2
```